# Is there a convenient syntax for exposing many ports in a Kubernetes service?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to model a 3 nodes Couchbase cluster on Kubernetes. I have created a separate replication controller for each node based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856214/how-to-model-stateful-components-in-kubernetes-using-replication-controller) suggestion. Now, I am trying to define a Kubernetes service for each node with all the required ports. But, as per [this](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Install/install-networkPorts.html) documentation, it will require many ports to be opened in service definition. Is there a convenient way to open range of ports in the service definition?

Answer (score 1):

> is there a convenient way to open range of ports in the service definition?

Not yet: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23864

I replied to the linked question about petset too.