# Kubernetes deployment where one of the pods gets different env

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

Is there any way I can have an AWS deployment using kubernetes where I have a variable and scalable number of pods for my app BUT the environment on the VM is different for a single host?

Basically I want that one of my pods doing a task that no of the other pods will do all the time. I am planning to control this using an environment variable.

Comment: You need a separate deployment for each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have multiple deployments, however if you are in need of `uniqueness` between the pods, you should consider `statefulsets` over deployments. However, deciding between `statefulset` and `deployment` is **mostly decided by the type of the application and it is a major decision.** so, using `statefulset` may not fit in as a 100% replacement for  a deployment.

In `statefulsets` each pod get its unique but non-random identity via its hostname.

For example, you can create a `mysql` statefulset using following:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: foo
  name: foo
spec:
  serviceName: mysql
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: foo
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: foo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql
        name: mysql
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: root
        image: mysql
        name: mysql
```

This would create three replicas of the pod:

```
k get pod -l app=foo
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
foo-0   1/1     Running   0          5m17s
foo-1   1/1     Running   0          5m14s
foo-2   1/1     Running   0          5m10s
```

Now you can fetch the hostname of the pods, the first pod will be always suffixed with `0` and 2nd with `1` and so on.

```
exec -it foo-0 --  hostname
foo-0
k exec -it foo-1 --  hostname
foo-1
k exec -it foo-2 --  hostname
foo-2
```

you can use `hostname` as selector do decide what action is required on which pod.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41733207/6309601) is one very good read on this.

Comment: Super useful info. Thanks so much!