# How to structure multiple common containers with different configurations

Tags: kubernetes

I have a container type that I will need to intermittently add and delete from my cluster, but each different container instance will need a unique configuration in the form of environment variables.

What is the best way to structure this with Kubernetes? Should I have a separate workload for each container? Should I have one common workload and update the pod with new containers as needed?

The containers are isolated applications that don't have anything to do with their siblings.

Comment: check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/q/68008219/6309601

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this you can use the jobs in kubernetes, if there is no use case of PVC or PV

For each different type create a new job with the different type of environment variables.

> I have a container type that I will need to intermittently add and
> delete from my cluster, but each different container instance will
> need a unique configuration in the form of environment variables.

configure multiple jobs or deployment in which you can give different options of environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

I do it by

- Having a common deployment yaml. You should mount configmaps as environment variables
- Packaging with Helm
- Deploying with different values.yaml for each instance.

As Harsh stated, you can also use Jobs pattern but I prefer having single file & many values files instead of different jobs definitions.. Because if a key changes, you will need to update all job definitions..